# Creating confusion matrix and calculating TP, TN,FP, FN

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, confusion-matrix

I want to generate a confusion matrix for `class 2`. There is a total of four input classes namely 0,1,2,3. In particular test data batch, there is no input `class 2`.

I have shown actual and predicted class, confusion matrix, and TP-TN-FP-FN values. Is this correct?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your actual and predicted matrix, the TP, FP, TN and FN values are correct for class 2.